# Binding code-behind variable to text in textbox in main window

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

I'm having issues binding text entered in a textbox to a variable in code behind.

Here's the xaml code for the textbox located in the main window:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Rotate1" Text="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=testvalue}" />
```

and in the code behind in main window:

```
private int testvalue { get; set;}
```

I know if it's the other way around I would have to update the source trigger on any change, but not sure what to do when it's changing variable to whatever the entered text is.

Answer (score 1):

try in code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public DependencyProperty TestValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("testvalue", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow));
  public int testvalue
  {
    get { return (int)GetValue(TestValueProperty); }
    set
    {
      SetValue(TestValueProperty, value);
    }
  }
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    testvalue = 6;
  }
}
```

in XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    x:Name="thisForm"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=thisForm, Path=testvalue}" />
</Window>
```

UPD: oh! of course! Remove Tag in CS and XAML code

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that did not work. When testing it, the value for the testvalue is still 0.

Comment: Didn't use the tag part but the dependencyProperty is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!