# How to clear text box on click in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a textbox and a button I want to clear the contents of textbox on button click. I am using MVVM prism.

My **XAML** is

```
  <TextBox  Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding 
       Path=TextProperty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="txtUserEntry2"/>

   <Button Content="Select" 
       Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" />
```

and In my **View Model**

```
    public string TextProperty
    {

        get
        {
            return selectedText;
        }
        set
        {

            selectedText = value;

            SetProperty(ref selectedText, value);
        }
    }

    //////.........

    private void MyCommandExecuted(object obj)
    {
        TextProperty= string.Empty;
        MessageBox.Show("Command Executed");
    }
```

But it does not clear the textbox. What am I missing ?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257972/binding-code-behind-variable-to-text-in-textbox-in-main-window/29258190#29258190)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because in your setter you are setting the field twice, one without firing PropertyChanged and the other with firing PropertyChanged , in the second set `SetProperty` will raise `PropertyChanged` only if there is a new value, but you already set the field to some value so the set  through the `SetProperty` will never raise PropertyChanged because you are setting it to the same value.

So in your setter you should remove:

```
selectedText = value;
```

Answer (score -2):

You are not triggering the PropertyChanged-event with the correct property name "TextProperty" - or am I missing something? I've never used Prism. 
Try:

```
public string TextProperty
{

    get
    {
        return selectedText;
    }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref selectedText, value, "TextProperty");
    }
}
```

or better yet:

```
private void MyCommandExecuted(object obj)
{
    SetProperty(TextProperty, string.Empty);
    MessageBox.Show("Command Executed");
}
```

and remove the SetProperty call from the property setter.

Comment: It's not a MVVM convention.